# Perl - search a word and print rest of line into variables

Tags: perl, variables, search, matching

I have an easy question. How can I make perl read a file, search for a specific word, and then if it finds a match, I want to print the rest of the line into individual variables.

The ascii file (called "region_list" that I wish to search contains has 3 lines:

hawaii 40 5 -140 -180

samoa -5 -25 -165 165

pacific 70 -65 290 110

Here's the code I have so far, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#
# Required Libraries
use Date::Calc qw(:all);
use Date::Manip;
use Math::Trig;
use warnings;
use Time::Local;
use POSIX 'strftime';
use lib '/usr/bin';
use Cwd qw();

my @region = ("hawaii", "samoa", "pacific");

open my $listreg1, "$BIN_DIR/region_list" or die "Could not open: $!";

  ($reg2,$max_lat, $min_lat, $max_lon, $min_lon) = split(" ",$listreg1);


   if ($region eq $reg2) {
            print "LUCREG $region $reg2 $max_lat, $min_lat, $max_lon, $min_lon \n";
    }



close $listreg1;
```

Answer (score 1):

With Perl 5.10 or higher, we can use the smart match ( ~~ ) operator to match the presence of a value into an array

```
open my $listreg1, '<', "$BIN_DIR/region_list" or die "Could not open: $!";

while( my $line = <$listreg1> ) {
  chomp $line;
  ($reg2, $max_lat, $min_lat, $max_lon, $min_lon) = split/ +/, $line;

   if( $reg2 ~~ \@region ) {
            print "LUCREG $region $reg2 $max_lat, $min_lat, $max_lon, $min_lon\n";
   }
}

close $listreg1;
```

Note, as @Joel says, that smartmatch operator will be marked experimental in 5.18, so it's probably a better choice use a CPAN module like [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/List-MoreUtils-0.33/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm) or simply grep.

Comment: due to continuing problems with smartmatch, it will be marked experimental in 5.18 which might lead to removal in future Perl version. I wouldn't write new code with it :-/